# Why am I seeing this 'failed to download' helm error when trying to upgrade a helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, newrelic

I am running a new relic chart in helm (from this repo -> https://github.com/newrelic/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/newrelic-logging, this is my output when running in my cluster:

`helm list -A -n kube-system`

```
NAME                            NAMESPACE.          REVISION.   UPDATED.      
newrelic-logging                kube-system         1           2021-06-23 18:54:54.383769 +0200 CEST   

STATUS.     CHART.                                  APP VERSION
deployed    newrelic-logging-1.4.7                  1.4.6
```

I am trying to set a specific value here: https://github.com/newrelic/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/newrelic-logging/values.yaml

To do this I am using `helm upgrade`. I have tried:

`helm upgrade newrelic-logging newrelic-logging-1.4.7 -f values.yaml -n kube-system`
`helm upgrade newrelic-logging-1.4.7 newrelic-logging --set updatedVal=0 -n kube-system`

However with these commands I am seeing the output:

`Error: failed to download "newrelic-logging-1.4.7"`

and

`Error: failed to download "newrelic-logging"`

Why and how do I fix this? I have also ran `helm repo update` and it completes with no error messages.

Unfortunately I don't see how this was initially setup as the previous employee has left the company and it's too risky to stop and redeploy right now.

Answer (score 4):

For those who land here for similar errors, Try updating helm repo

```
helm repo update
```

If you already had the helm repo, re-adding it would not update it. You have to do it with the update command. Above command will update all the helm repos while the following command will update a specific repo

```
helm repo update <repo name>
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the current chart with new values without upgrading the chart version, you can try:

```
helm upgrade --reuse-values -f values.yaml newrelic-logging kube-system/newrelic-logging
```